# Any guarantees with vector<bool> iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool#Notes) says that the iterators for the `vector<bool>` specialization are implementation defined and many not support traits like `ForwardIterator` (and therefore `RandomAccessIterator`).

[cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) adds a mysterious "most":

> The pointer and iterator types used by the container are not
>   necessarily neither pointers nor conforming iterators, although they
>   shall simulate most of their expected behavior.

I don't have access to the official specification. Are there *any* iterator behaviors guaranteed for the `vector<bool>` iterators?

More concretely, how would one write standards-compliant code to insert an item in the middle of a `vector<bool>`? The following works on several compilers that I tried:

```
std::vector<bool> v(4);
int k = 2;
v.insert(v.begin() + k, true);
```

Will it always?

Comment: In one word: Nope! The `std::vector<bool>` specialization is broke,

Comment: In one word: Yup! Unless you subscribe to the (far too common) notion that if it isn't perfect it's useless. Engineering is about making things work, not complaining that they aren't what you'd like them to be.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Will `std::sort` work on iterators from a `vector<bool>.` If the answer to that question is "I don't know" (and it is), then things are not working. Yes, ***users*** may write code that takes iterators from a `vector<bool>`. But there are no guarantees that any standard library algorithm will work with them.

Comment: @NicolBolas - C++14 [vector.bool]/2 seems to disagree with you.

Comment: @PeteBecker: And C++14 [forward.iterators]/1 agrees with me. See my answer below.

Comment: I feel agree with everybody here. First of all there are guarantees. Secondly, `vector<bool>` is a broken mess. If the standard didn't define it then a C++ implementation couldn't supply that optimization, much the same as it can't supply an efficient `realloc` based default for `vector`: the general interface provides access to the internals, and we're screwed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "*If the standard didn't define it then a C++ implementation couldn't supply that optimization*" The problem with `vector<bool>` is that it's *not* an "optimization". Unlike `realloc`-based reallocation, in order to allow compression of `bool`, the *visible behavior* of `vector` has to change. The problem is that the committee felt the need to call it a specialization of `vector` instead of what it really is: a whole new type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental problem with `vector<bool>`'s iterators is that they are not ForwardIterators. C++14 [forward.iterators]/1 requires that ForwardIterators' `reference` type be `T&` or `const T&`, as appropriate.

Any function which takes a forward iterator over a range of `T`s is allowed to do this:

```
T &t = *it;
t = //Some value.
```

However, `vector<bool>`'s `reference` types are not `bool&`; they're a [proxy object that is convertible to and assignable from a `bool`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) They act like a `bool`, but they are *not* a `bool`. As such, this code is illegal:

```
bool &b = *it;
```

It would be attempting to get an lvalue reference to a temporary created from the proxy object. That's not allowed.

Therefore, you *cannot* use `vector<bool>`'s iterators in any function that takes ForwardIterators or higher.

However, your code doesn't necessarily have to care about that. As long as you control what code you pass those `vector<bool>` iterators to, and you don't do anything that violates how they behave, then you're fine.

As far as their interface is concerned, they act like RandomAccessIterators, except for when they don't (see above). So you can offset them with integers with constant time complexity and so forth.

`vector<bool>` is fine, so long as you don't treat it like a `vector` that contains `bool`s. Your code will work because it uses `vector<bool>`'s own interface, which it obviously accepts.

It would not work if you passed a pair of `vector<bool>` iterators to `std::sort`.

---

C++20 update:

Because the C++20 concept iterator categories allow for proxy iterators, `vector<bool>::iterator` is now a valid `std::random_access_iterator`. This means you can pass them to any algorithm that is constrained on that concept or a higher-level one.

However, these are only the algorithms in the `std::ranges` namespace. The regular `std::` algorithms still use the old definition, which `vector<bool>::iterator` doesn't allow.

---

C++23 update.

[Algorithms which take non-mutable old-style are now required to take types conforming to the corresponding iterator concept.](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-4.4) So if a function took a non-mutable RandomAccessIterator, then it is required to accept a `std::random_access_iterator` conforming type.

Comment: Where did you find a requirement that `std::sort` use `T &t = *it;`? Since that obviously violates the requirement in [vector.bool]/2, it's not allowed. The usual approach is to do `*it = //Some value`, which is how proxy iterators are expected to be used.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*Where did you find a requirement that std::sort use T &t = *it;?*" I didn't. However, because it takes RandomAccessIterators, `sort` is permitted to do so, since that is an operation that is permissible on RandomAccessIterators. And no, it would not violate [vector.bool]/2; note that the behavior of `vector<bool>::iterator::reference` is part of the "Unless described below" part.

Comment: Isn't it easy to get some vague supporting evidence by simply trying it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Trying it solves nothing. One `sort` implementation may not use references. But the `partition` implementation might. Or it might not. Or libc++'s implementation might not, while libstdc++ might. So long as the standard *permits* implementations to use it, you *cannot assume* that your code will work.

Comment: @NicolBolas - your argument is actually inside out. The standard has to be read as a whole, and if `std::sort` is implemented in a way that assumes that `std::vector<bool>` has some properties that it, in fact, doesn't have, then the implementation is wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But you're not reading the standard "as a whole". The standard says "***Unless described below***". The behavior of `vector<bool>`'s iterators are explicitly "described below". And that behavior *does not conform* to RandomAccessIterator. Therefore, you cannot pass them to `sort`. The spec is saying "it works like `vector` except where we say it doesn't". The spec is *not* saying "it works like `vector`, and everything else in the standard library must be adjusted to compensate, but we won't say what those adjustments have to be."

Comment: @NicolBolas - my apologies. I mistakenly responded to arguments that you didn't make. So I'm going to radically change direction in my next comment.

Comment: What requirement for forward iterators do you say that `std::vector<bool>::iterator` violates? Note that in C++03, `*it` returned `T&`; in C++11 that requirement was removed, and replaced with the operational semantics `*r = o` for output iterators, coupled with the requirement that `*r++` returns a `reference`, which is in turn defined as `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference`, with no further constraints. This was done specifically to permit proxy iterators.

Comment: @PeteBecker: This requirement: "if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference
to `const T`," Again, just read C++14 [forward.iterators]/1.

Comment: @NicolBolas - no. We know how to say `T&`, and would not use "reference to `T`" to mean `T&`. That sentence is about the **modifiability** of the underlying `T`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*That sentence is about the modifiability of the underlying T.*" If that's true, why would it be talking about a "reference to `const T`"? Furthermore, the standard *frequently* uses the phrase "reference to" when referring to actual language references. Indeed, in prose text the standard rarely refers to `T&`, preferring "reference to T" instead. A great example of this is [basic.def.odr]/5.6.

Comment: @NicolBolas - um, the language portion of the standard uses rather different formalisms from the library portion, for obvious reasons: it has to say what `T&` means. And keep in mind that the purpose of those changes was to make proxy iterators **work**; maybe if you squint just right you can come up with an interpretation that makes that effort a total failure, but that's at best ungenerous.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think, since it was probably Pete Becker who wrote that into the standard, when he says he knows the intention, he does. But a different matter is whether current compiler vendors have understood that intention. There's so much strange these days.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*um, the language portion of the standard uses rather different formalisms from the library portion, for obvious reasons: it has to say what T& means.*" If you're saying that the phrase "reference to T" means something different depending on where it's written in the standard, then I would say that the standard is *broken*. The standard *constantly* uses "reference to T" as a way of saying `T&`; why should I believe that it means "some object that kinda acts like a T" in this particular case? If that's what the standard was meant to say, then it should *actually* say it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "*I think, since it was probably Pete Becker who wrote that into the standard, when he says he knows the intention, he does.*" I'm sure he does know what the intention is. I'm saying that, if that was what was intended, it didn't achieve that goal. Just like if you intend to write "if(x == 4)" but you instead write "if(x = 4)"... you still wrote "if(x = 4)", regardless of what your intentions were.

Comment: @NicolBolas - to come full circle, your position is "if it isn't perfect it's useless".

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*to come full circle, your position is "if it isn't perfect it's useless".*" No. My position is, "If the standard doesn't *guarantee* behavior, then your code has undefined behavior." I rely on undefined behavior every day. But you should know when you're doing it, and you shouldn't do it just because it's easier. Also, as to the issue with proxy iterators, [Eric Niebler seems to agree with me about what the standard says.](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0022r1.html#motivation-and-scope) His point #1 is exactly what I said.

Comment: @NicolBolas - yes, to repeat myself, if you squint just right you can insist that the fix to proxy iterators was a total failure. That position can also be a political argument to strengthen the case for a set of changes, rather than a formal technical argument.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*if you squint just right you can insist that the fix to proxy iterators was a total failure.*" I'm sorry, but I have problems understanding how saying that "reference to T" means "*reference to T*" constitutes "squinting really hard." And it seems like poisoning the well to claim that people who don't agree with your interpretation of the standard are only doing so to as "a political argument" rather than "because that's the most obvious interpretation of what the standard says."

Comment: "`reference` **is a** reference to `T`" is not a requirement; it's a description. "`reference` **shall be** a reference to `T`" would be a requirement. Of course, that doesn't address your contention that changing `T&` in C++03 to "reference to `T`" in C++11 was not intended to change anything.

Comment: Why is `iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::reference` `vector<bool>::reference`? Can't an implementation define `iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::reference` to be `bool&` to meet the requirement of forward iterator?

Comment: @xskxzr: Because such a definition would be a *lie*. `vector<bool>` does not contain `bool`s, so no function on the type can return a `bool&`. It must instead return a proxy object.

Comment: But is this specified in the standard? Or is it a standard defect?

Comment: @xskxzr: Yes, it's specified in the standard. And it can't be a defect because it's not possible for `iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::reference` to be `bool&`. Because `bool &b = (*it);` would be ill-formed, because it's a proxy object, not a reference.

Comment: But why is it not possible for `iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::reference` to be `bool&`? I mean the standard does not require indirection of an iterator to return the object it points to. In fact, it does not even define the corresponding object an iterator points to. For example, it [does not specify](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:containers.container.requirements) the semantic of `begin` member function.

Comment: @xskxzr: Because `iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::reference val = *it;` would be ill-formed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166154/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-nicol-bolas).

Comment: I can't find where in the standard `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is required to be "like a random access iterator", meaning having things like `iter1 - iter2`, `iter + offset`, `iter[offset]`, etc. I can't even find `--iter`, but it's implied by `reverse_iterator` being `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>`. Do you know if it's required for `vector<bool>` iterators to have all the operations for random access iterators, except that they have to deal in proxy references?

Comment: @Justin: It's the part that says "Unless described below, all operations have the same requirements and semantics as the primary vector template". The behavior of iterators with respect to random access is not "described below", so it is "like a random access iterator".

Comment: For the record, the situation has changed a bit in C++23. With the merge of https://wg21.link/p2408, the [requirements for algorithms talking forward iterators have been changed](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-4.4), meaning that `vector<bool>::iterator` can be used as where a non-mutable `ForwardIterator` is required -- because `vector<bool>::iterator` does actually model `forward_iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

C++14 [vector.bool]/2:

> Unless described below, all operations have the same requirements and
>   semantics as the primary `vector` template, except that operations
>   dealing with the `bool` value type map to bit values in the container
>   storage and `allocator_traits::construct` (20.7.8.2) is not used to
>   construct these values.

Comment: I've also found [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#dataraces-2) (a bit obvious).